# Why is a subquery in a WHERE statement so slow in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

The following query takes a little over 1 second to complete and returns 24k results.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    (ad_name)
FROM
    marketing.fbk_ad_stats_daily AS marketing
WHERE
    date_start >= subdate(CURRENT_DATE,30)
    and spend >1
```

When I use said query as a condition in the following WHERE statement:

```
SELECT
    name,
    tracking_key
FROM
    marketing.ads
WHERE
    name IN
             (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                 (ad_name)
             FROM
                 marketing.fbk_ad_stats_daily
             WHERE
                 date_start >= subdate(CURRENT_DATE,30))
```

it runs for dozens of minutes, I shut it down before seeing how long it actually takes. But when I take the **results** of the original query and use them as a condition in the WHERE statement like this...

```
SELECT
    name,
    tracking_key
FROM
    marketing.ads
    where name 
in ('bnj-fbk-m-us-5db72043 c18 - MF-Image18-US-OS-Android',
'bnj-fbk-m-us-5db72043 c17 - MF-Image17-US-OS-Android',
'bnj-fbk-m-us-f72f73c8 c33 - MF-Image33-US-OS-Android',
'bnj-fbk-m-us-f72f73c8 c35 - MF-Image35-US-OS-Android',
'bnj-fbk-m-us-5db72043 c6 - MF-Image6-US-OS-Android', ... etc... x 24k rows... )
```

I get a blazing fast runtime of 3 seconds.
What explains the difference between the two approaches? Why is the second query not a linear combination of the two queries?

The explain for the second query is:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  <subquery2> ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
1   SIMPLE  ads ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  826919  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2   MATERIALIZED    fbk_ad_stats_daily  range   ix_fbk_ad_stats_daily_date_start    ix_fbk_ad_stats_daily_date_start    6   (null)  399630  Using index condition
```

the explain for the third query is this:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  ads ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  826919  Using where
```

but i don't understand explains enough to discern the answer

Comment: While you were writing this question, did any suggestion pop up that contained something like `use EXPLAIN to profile your query`?

Comment: No. I don't understand explain results though. The explain results for the second query are this:

Comment: *"The explain results for the second query are this:"* Are what? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55262964/edit) the explain output in the question for both queries

Comment: Post the execution plan in the query, not the comments. That `DISTINCT` can only cause delays though. You don't care about individual values in the subquery, only if a value exists or not. There's no reason to execute a `DISTINCT` operation for this

Comment: I'll upvote your question if you add the execution plan of both queries.

Comment: A `DISTINCT` needs to consume all results, sort it and deduplicate. That's very expensive. The second query correlates that expensive operation with *another* result set. The server now has two options - perform the DISTINCT and join with the outer table. Or do a DISTINCT for each value in the outer table. That's probably what's going on here.

Comment: If the `name` and `ad_name` don't have proper indexes or statistics, the server can easily pick the *wrong* execution plan.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  Sorry, added to the main post.

Comment: Can you also provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` output for both queries and `EXPLAIN <query>; SHOW WARNINGS;` for both queries? The `SHOW WARNINGS;` will provide more info how MySQL optimizer rewrites/handles the queries it will most likely confirm @PanagiotisKanavos comments

Comment: I'm not sure if it is just a typo, but according to what you've included in the question you are NOT using _"said query as a condition in the following WHERE statement"_; the one in the WHERE has dropped the condition on `spend`.

Answer (score 3):

It's slow because MySQL optimizer is generating a suboptimal plan for the statement.

We can use MySQL `EXPLAIN` statement to see details of the execution plan.

---

To answer the question, worst case, MySQL could looking at that subquery as a dependent correlated subquery, such that it gets executed for each row processed by the outer query.

That is, the MySQL execution plan might be getting a row for the outer query, and then checking the condition in the `WHERE` clause. To do that, MySQL might be executing the subquery, materializing the results of that into a temporary-ish table. Note that the DISTINCT keyword is going to cause MySQL to perform a unique sort, to eliminate duplicates. Once that result is ready, then MySQL can scan the result to see if the value from the outer row is found. Depending on the version of the MySQL optimizer, there may not be an index.  If a match is not found, the row from the outer query is discarded.

Then MySQL gets the next row from the outer query, and performs the same process. Executing the subquery, materializing the result, and scanning that to see of the value of `name` is found.

That's probably the worst case execution plan for large sets.

Or, it could just be that the subquery is materialized once, but there's no index, so every row in the subquery has to be scanned for a matching `name`, for every row from the outer query. With 24,000 rows returned by the subquery, that's potentially 24,000 string matches for each row in the outer query that gets discarded.

Another possibility is that MySQL is waiting on locks to be obtained, e.g. the tables are MyISAM and there are concurrent DML operations holding table locks.

---

Do we want more of an explanation of possible reasons for slow performance, or should we just jump to some alternative query patterns for better performance?

Some recommendations to consider:

- a join operation or `EXISTS` subquery rather than an `IN` subquery
- qualify all column references
- don't include extraneous parens

---

Demonstration of a materializing the query results into a derived table, with a JOIN operation. Improvements to the MySQL optimizer in more recent versions will allow automatic creation of an index on the derived table, for improved performance. But if the derived table is the driving table for the join, MySQL can make use of an index with `name` as the leading column. For example, a covering index for the query would be `... ON marketing.ads (name,tracking_key)`.

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.tracking_key 
  FROM ( SELECT d.ad_name
           FROM marketing.fbk_ad_stats_daily d
          WHERE d.date_start >= CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL -30 DAY
            AND d.spend > 1
          GROUP
             BY d.ad_name
       ) n
  JOIN marketing.ads t
    ON t.name = n.ad_name
```

Sometimes an `EXISTS` pattern will give suitable performance, with appropriate indexes available. Note that the subquery is related to the outer row, the value of `ad_name` from the subquery needs to match the `name` value from the outer query.

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.tracking_key 
  FROM marketing.ads t
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM marketing.fbk_ad_stats_daily d
                 WHERE d.date_start >= CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL -30 DAY
                   AND d.spend      > 1
                   AND d.ad_name    = t.name    /*correlated to outer row*/
              )
```

A query of this form will require that *every* row from `t` will need to be checked, so the subquery will be executed for each row examined (and not otherwise discarded) by the outer query.

Comment: So if I understand, and if what you're saying matches this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery ... "In the above nested query the inner query has to be re-executed for each employee."..... my subquery is executed for every row that exists in marketing.ads? AS OPPOSED TO it executing a single time, storing the results and being checked by  every row in marketing.ads ?

Comment: @JoshFlori: yes, the explanation for a correlated subquery is what i was getting at... one possible explanation for the slow performance. i'm not seeing that your subquery is actually correlated (column references aren't qualified, so that leaves me guessing which columns are in which tables... the MySQL optimizer can figure it out, because it can look up the table definitions real fast, it's a chore for the human reader. This is just *one* possible explanation. I wouldn't think MySQL 5.6, 5.7 or 8.0 optimizer would generate a correlated subquery plan for a subquery that isn't correlated)

Comment: *"worst case, MySQL could looking at that subquery as a dependent correlated subquery, such that it gets executed for each row processed by the outer query."* @JoshFlori that's why i asked for `EXPLAIN <query>; SHOW WARNINGS;` in the comments that way you can see if the optimizer handles this like a subquery or co-related subquery. the `SHOW WARNINGS;` shows you the optimzed query when used in combination with `EXPLAIN <query>`

Comment: i advice to replace the `GROUP BY` with `DISTINCT` for the first query as it does not have a implict `ORDER BY` like `GROUP BY` has before MySQL 8.0 or add `ORDER BY NULL` to disable the implict sort on `GROUP BY` it might give extra performance @JoshFlori

Comment: @RaymondNijland: for a large derived table, with the equality predicate in the join, more recent versions of MySQL will create an index; which would necessitate a using filesort operation. For older versions of MySQL that won't create an index on the derived table, adding ORDER BY NULL would theoretically allow the GROUP BY to be satisfied with an operation other than "Using filesort" ala Oracle's use of a hash... but I don't believe older versions of MySQL do any operations other than the sort. We can use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan, and we measure/compare performance of execution